# Do Django fetches ALL database objects for the paginator function and make it inefficient?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from .model                import blog

b = blog.objects.all()
p = Paginator(b, 2)
```

The above code is from the official Django Pagination Documentation.
Can somebody please explain me **how this is not inefficient**
If I have a table with many records? Doesn't the above code fetch everything from the db and then just chops it down? Destroying the purpose of Pagination...

Comment: No it does *not* fetch all the items. Note that a queryset is *lazy*: it will simply slice the queryset, and thus perform the query with a `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can somebody please explain me how this is not inefficient If I have a table with many records?

**`QuerySet`s are *lazy***. The `blog.objects.all()` will *not* retrieve the records from the database, *unless* you "*consume*" the `QuerySet`. But you did not do that, and so will the paginator not do that either. You "consume" a queryset by iterating over it, calling `len(..)` over it, converting it to a `str(..)`ing, and some other functions. But as long as you do not do that. The `QuerySet` is just an object that represents a "query" that Django *will* perform if necessary.

The `Paginator` will construct a `QuerySet` that is a *sliced* variant of the queryset you pass. It will first call `queryset.count()` to retrieve the number of objects, and thus make a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM …` query (where we thus do *not* retrieve the elements itself), and then use a sliced variant that looks like `queryset[:2]` that will thus look like `SELECT … FROM … LIMIT 2`. The count is performed to determine the number of pages that exist.

In short, it will thus construct new queries, and perform these on the database. Normally these limit the amount of data returned.