# How much Django is faster to load 20,000 QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I just want to know that how much Django is faster. 
if my model has 20,000 objects and I want to load them all in a single request like.

```
data = my_model.objects.all()
```

Then how much it takes time to loads on the client browser if he/she requesting the my_model data.

if we load only 10 list-objects does it is more than faster than the first approach?

```
data = my_model.objects.all()[:10]
```

Which is faster?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622976/how-do-you-calculate-program-run-time-in-python

Comment: As long as you do not *iterate* over the data, it will not even fetch any records at all.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my awnser, I don't know about it. :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you more elaborate.

Comment: @ManinderSingh: see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564167/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you now i got it.